# Parse out all characters before the last space

Tags: c#, indexing

I need to take a line such as:

> Fruit Tasty Brand Apples 3

and separate the quantity and the part description.  I'm able to get the quantity of 3 by doing this:

```
foreach (var firstPass in textBox1.Lines)
{

    {//trim it up
        string firstTrimmed = firstPass.TrimEnd();

        if (firstTrimmed.Length > 0)
        {//find the qty
            int locateQty = firstTrimmed.LastIndexOf(" ") + 1;
            var qty = (firstTrimmed.Substring(locateQty));



            textBox2.Text = qty.ToString();
```

But I'm not able to get the full description (Fruit Tasty Brand Apples ) before the quantity to go to `textBox3` for example so that I can treat the description and quantity as different entities with the hopes of adding up the combined quantity of duplicate descriptions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the second overload of `Substring()` function: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aka44szs

That takes the length of the string and can be used with your `locateQty` variable, since the position of the last space char is zero based, it will be equal to the length of the description.

```
string description = firstTrimmed.Substring(0, locateQty);
```

Comment: Please don't post .NET 1.1 links unless the question is about .NET 1.1.

Answer (score 2):

You should be able to get what you need by using `Substring` from zero:

```
var descr = firstTrimmed.Substring(0, locateQty-2);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
string value = "Fruit Tasty Brand Apples 3";
int index1 = value.LastIndexOf(' ');
if (index1 != -1)
{
    Console.WriteLine(index1);
    Console.WriteLine(value.Substring(index1)); // 3
    Console.WriteLine(value.Substring(0, index1-2)); // Fruit Tasty Brand Apples
}
```